# Change Named Pipe Access Permissions

Tags: c#, windows, security, named-pipes

I have created a named pipe using `System.IO.Pipes`. It worked fine until I had to run the program in admin mode. When elevated, the client can no longer connect (client is not running elevated). If I run the client as administrator, it connects fine so it looks like a permissions issue. I've been researching how to fix this and have been unsuccessful (I find dealing with Windows security mind boggling). My goal is to allow any client - whether elevated or not - to be able to connect to the pipe.

The first thing I changed was opening the pipe with access rights:

```
pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream(pipeName,
                                       PipeDirection.InOut,
                                       1,
                                       PipeTransmissionMode.Message,
                                       PipeOptions.Asynchronous,
                                       0x4000,
                                       0x400,
                                       null,
                                       HandleInheritability.Inheritable,
                                       PipeAccessRights.ChangePermissions | PipeAccessRights.AccessSystemSecurity);
```

Then I cobbled this code together. Everything works until the `SetEntriesInAcl` call which fails with:

> Error: 0x534
>   "No mapping between account names and security IDs was done."

```
IntPtr ownerSid = IntPtr.Zero;
IntPtr groupSid = IntPtr.Zero;
IntPtr dacl = IntPtr.Zero, newDacl = IntPtr.Zero;
IntPtr sacl = IntPtr.Zero;
IntPtr securityDescriptor = IntPtr.Zero;
if (SUCCEEDED(GetSecurityInfo(pipeServer.SafePipeHandle.handle.DangerousGetHandle(),                                                  
                              SE_OBJECT_TYPE.SE_KERNEL_OBJECT,
                              SECURITY_INFORMATION.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
                              out ownerSid,
                              out groupSid,
                              out dacl,
                              out sacl,
                              out securityDescriptor))) {
    EXPLICIT_ACCESS ea = new EXPLICIT_ACCESS();
    BuildExplicitAccessWithName(ref ea, "Everyone", GENERIC_ALL, ACCESS_MODE.GRANT_ACCESS, NO_INHERITANCE);
    // Next line fails
    if (SUCCEEDED(SetEntriesInAcl(1, ref ea, dacl, out newDacl))) {
        uint retval = SetSecurityInfo(handle,
                             SE_OBJECT_TYPE.SE_KERNEL_OBJECT,
                             SECURITY_INFORMATION.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
                             IntPtr.Zero,
                             IntPtr.Zero,
                             newDacl,
                             IntPtr.Zero);
                        // Haven't reached this point yet
    }
}
```

The `BuildExplicitAccessWithName` function does not return a value but seems to succeed ok. This is what it looks like after the call:
[image]

I would appreciate any help here.

(All the Win32 functions and data types were found on pinvoke.net. Also, I'm using Windows 10.)

Comment: See [`PipeStream.GetAccessControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.pipestream.getaccesscontrol).

Comment: @eryksun Thanks. That led me down the right path. I'll type up an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ended up not having to use any native calls. The [`PipeSecurity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.pipesecurity%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) class worked. The trick was I had to pass it to the constructor:

```
// Creates a PipeSecurity that allows users read/write access
PipeSecurity CreateSystemIOPipeSecurity()
{
    PipeSecurity pipeSecurity = new PipeSecurity();

    var id = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.AuthenticatedUserSid, null);

    // Allow Everyone read and write access to the pipe. 
    pipeSecurity.SetAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule(id, PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite, AccessControlType.Allow));

    return pipeSecurity;
}
```

Use that function when creating the pipe:

```
PipeSecurity pipeSecurity = CreateSystemIOPipeSecurity();
pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream(pipeName,
                                       PipeDirection.InOut,
                                       1,
                                       PipeTransmissionMode.Message,
                                       PipeOptions.Asynchronous,
                                       0x4000,
                                       0x400,
                                       pipeSecurity,
                                       HandleInheritability.Inheritable);
```

Comment: Note that the constructor in .NET Core doesn't take a PipeSecurity parameter, so I think you have to use the PipeStream.SetAccessControl method instead.

Comment: Thank you for following up to answer your own question with this fantastically excellent answer; it fixed my problem instantly. I was futzing around trying to de-elevate the server somehow, but that was totally the wrong approach, this works simpler and is way better, letting the pipe server retain its security unchanged.