# C# Change Named Pipe Access Permissions

Tags: c#, named-pipes

I am getting an Unauthorized Access exception when I try to add security to my pipe. I gather that this needs to be defined when I create the pipe, or at least add a permission to change the pipe, but I don't see how to do that either. All examples online have too many arguments. My compiler says that NamedPipeServerStream maxes out at 7 and does not have any security options. [Microsoft agrees with me.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes.namedpipeserverstream?view=net-8.0)

```
using System.IO.Pipes;
NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer;
pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream("PipeName", PipeDirection.InOut, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);
PipeSecurity clientPipeSecurity = new PipeSecurity();                    
//PipeAccessRule clientAccessRule = new PipeAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null), PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite, AccessControlType.Allow);
//clientPipeSecurity.AddAccessRule(clientAccessRule);     
PipeAccessRule clientAccessRule = new PipeAccessRule("Domain Users", PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite, AccessControlType.Allow);
clientPipeSecurity.AddAccessRule(clientAccessRule);            
                
pipeServer.SetAccessControl(clientPipeSecurity);
```

Did include the wrong library? Why won't this compile like [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51546328/change-named-pipe-access-permissions) say it should? All I can think is that those examples are too old .NET has dropped that option for some reason.

```
pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream("DAQUpdater",
      PipeDirection.InOut,
      1,
      PipeTransmissionMode.Message,
      PipeOptions.Asynchronous,
      0x4000,
      0x400,
      pipeSecurity);
```

> 'NamedPipeServerStream' does not contain a constructor that takes 8 arguments

Comment: When I visit your link, I don't see it agreeing with you.  In fact I think you linked the wrong page and actually want https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes.namedpipeserverstream.-ctor?view=net-8.0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59969943/how-to-set-pipesecurity-of-namedpipeserverstream-in-net-core

Comment: Thank you Hans! That was the post I was missing!