# How to configure NamedPipes permissions when using gRPC ASP.NET Core over NamedPipes

Tags: c#, grpc, named-pipes

I have a gRPC Server using ASP.Net Core running as a Windows Service. I also have a gRPC Client that is running as a limited user. If I run the gRPC Client as an admin they can communicate just fine. When I run it as a non admin I get the following error:

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Access to the path is denied. (localhost:80)

This is a permissions issue. According to this stack overflow question [Change Named Pipe Access Permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51546328/change-named-pipe-access-permissions) I could change the permissions when creating the NamedPipeServerStream if I was using raw Named Pipes.

gRPCs use of named pipe is less direct.

```
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(serverOption =>
    {
        serverOption.ListenNamedPipe(HelloWorldInfo.gRpcPipeName,
            listenOptions =>
            {
                listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http2;
            });
    });
builder.Services.AddGrpc();
```

Is there a way to configure Kestrel to add the DACL to the named pipe, so that the limited user can communicate?

A second options would be to obtain the named pipe after the server starts, and add the DACL. But NamedPipes can handle this configuration already.  It is just a matter of how.

I tried setting the PipeSecurity while configuring Kestrel like this.

```
var pipeSecurity = CreateSystemIOPipeSecurity();
builder.WebHost.UseNamedPipes(opts =>
{
    opts.PipeSecurity = pipeSecurity;
    opts.CurrentUserOnly = false;
});
```

But I get

System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address http://pipe:/HelloWorldPipe: address already in use.

Comment: Have you read [this MS docs article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/named-pipe-security-and-access-rights) yet? Seems like you can specify security descriptors for a named pipe. You could get the SID of the current user, and give it ReadWright access rights using the [PipeSecurity class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes.pipesecurity?view=net-8.0) that you already mentioned. I currently don't have time to try it out myself, otherwise I would try it and if it works write it up as an answer. Interesting question!

Comment: But as you said, I think the PipeSecurity has to be defined before the Kestrel gets configured. I would try something like this: `using (NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream(pipeName, PipeDirection.InOut, NamedPipeServerStream.MaxAllowedServerInstances, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, PipeOptions.Asynchronous,  0,  0, pipeSecurity))
{
    // Your existing Kestrel setup code here
}`

Comment: The article you linked to is helpful, particularly what permissions to set. I will probably use the native functions linked unless we discover a better way.

Comment: When using gRPC with Named Pipe, I don't explicitly create the named pipe.  I just pass the name of the Named Pipe to the ListenNamedPipe method. If there is a way to pass the named pipe instance to gRPC it would solve my problem, but I don't see a way to do that.

Comment: Ah dang, I never tried out named pipes with gRPC in C#. I used Unix sockets once for interprocess communication, and if I remember correctly there you could create a socket and pass it to the Kestrel..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It got me some trouble as well, the underlying error code is not nicely translated to the message that pipe is already in use.

The trick is that the server process identity has to have not only readwrite permissions but also create pipe permission.

When having only read write permission and the initial pipe creation succeeds but the subsequent pool connection creation fails due to the ACL restrictions.

Add to your PipeSecurity creation method following

```cs
pipeSecurity.AddAccessRule(
    new PipeAccessRule(
        WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Owner!,
        PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite | PipeAccessRights.CreateNewInstance,
        AccessControlType.Allow
    )
);
```